# Validating Password And Confirm Password Fields Whenever One Or The Other Fields Model Changes (Each Keystroke) With Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I currently have an Angular Directive that validates a password and confirm password field as matching. It works to a point, it does throw an error when the passwords do not match. However, it doesn't throw the error until you have entered data in both fields. How can I make it so the error for mismatched passwords is thrown as soon as you enter data in one field or the other?

Here is the directive (it has to be added to both fields that need to match):

```
.directive('passwordVerify', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
      require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
         //if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

         // watch own value and re-validate on change
         scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
            validate();
         });

         // observe the other value and re-validate on change
         attrs.$observe('passwordVerify', function(val) {
            validate();
         });

         var validate = function() {
            // values
            var val1 = ngModel.$viewValue;
            var val2 = attrs.passwordVerify;

           // set validity
           ngModel.$setValidity('passwordVerify', !val1 || !val2 || val1 === val2);
        };
      }
   };
});
```

And here is the directive in my form:

```
<div class="small-5 columns">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
        <label>
            Password
            <input 
                ng-class="{ notvalid: submitted && add_user_form.user_password.$invalid }" 
                class="instructor-input" 
                id="user_password" 
                type="password" 
                name='user_password' 
                placeholder="password" 
                value='' 
                required 
                ng-model="user.user_password" 
                password-verify="[[user.confirm_password]]"
            >
        </label>
        <p class="help-text">
            <span class="   ">Required</span>
        </p>
        <div 
            class="help-block" 
            ng-messages="add_user_form.user_password.$error" 
            ng-show="add_user_form.user_password.$touched || add_user_form.user_password.$dirty"
        >
        <span class="red">
            <div ng-messages-include="/app/views/messages.html" ></div>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="small-12 columns">
    <label>
        Confirm Password
        <input 
            ng-class="{ notvalid: submitted && add_user_form.confirm_password.$invalid }" 
            class="instructor-input" 
            id="confirm_password" 
            ng-model="user.confirm_password" 
            name="confirm_password" 
            type="password" 
            placeholder="confirm password" 
            name="user_confirm_passsword" 
            required 
            password-verify="[[user.user_password]]"
        >
    </label>
    <p class="help-text">
        <span class="   ">
            Enter matching password
        </span>
    </p>
    <div 
        class="help-block" 
        ng-messages="add_user_form.confirm_password.$error" 
        ng-show="add_user_form.confirm_password.$dirty || add_user_form.confirm_password.$touched "
    >
        <span class="red">
            <div 
                ng-messages-include="/app/views/messages.html"
            ></div>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need to call it like this password-verify="[[user.confirm_password]]", just curious since I havent seen [[]] in attribute call before ?

Comment: Yeah it wigs out if you don't. I got this directive from someone else and it's a little shaky. I think it is validating the data in the attribute instead of the model, that's why its in [[]], which by the way is my replacement for {{}} because I'm using a handlebars template. So the way he coded it is to enter the data from the model into the attribute directly instead of comparing the model's in the directive. Any thoughts on how I could change that? I'm new to angular, normally do everything MVC server side with PHP.

Comment: Hmm, cant you pass the second input field model in the directive and compare with current input field model on change ? If you put the code on js-bin or jsFiddle I'll probably be able to help

Comment: I can't even recreate it on jsfiddle .... https://jsfiddle.net/sueLvc0r/

Comment: Maybe we can collaborate on jsFiddle :) https://jsfiddle.net/sueLvc0r/#&togetherjs=GOFl96fvAw

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just change the last check:

```
ngModel.$setValidity('passwordVerify', !val1 || !val2 || val1 === val2);
```

**to:**

```
ngModel.$setValidity('passwordVerify', val1 === val2);
```

Here's a *working* version:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular
    .module('app', ['ngMessages'])
    .controller('mainCtrl', mainCtrl)
    .directive('passwordVerify', passwordVerify);

  function mainCtrl($scope) {
    // Some code
  }

  function passwordVerify() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
      require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
        if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

        // watch own value and re-validate on change
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
          validate();
        });

        // observe the other value and re-validate on change
        attrs.$observe('passwordVerify', function(val) {
          validate();
        });

        var validate = function() {
          // values
          var val1 = ngModel.$viewValue;
          var val2 = attrs.passwordVerify;

          // set validity
          ngModel.$setValidity('passwordVerify', val1 === val2);
        };
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-messages/1.5.7/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <form name="add_user_form">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : add_user_form.user_password.$dirty && add_user_form.user_password.$invalid }">
        <p class="help-text">Enter password</p>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="user_password" name="user_password" placeholder="password" required ng-model="user.user_password" password-verify="{{user.confirm_password}}">
        <div class="help-block" ng-messages="add_user_form.user_password.$error" ng-if="add_user_form.user_password.$dirty">
          <p ng-message="required">This field is required</p>
          <p ng-message="minlength">This field is too short</p>
          <p ng-message="maxlength">This field is too long</p>
          <p ng-message="required">This field is required</p>
          <p ng-message="passwordVerify">No match!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : add_user_form.confirm_password.$dirty && add_user_form.confirm_password.$invalid }">
        <p class="help-text">Enter matching password</p>
        <input class="form-control" id="confirm_password" ng-model="user.confirm_password" name="confirm_password" type="password" placeholder="confirm password" required password-verify="{{user.user_password}}">
        <div class="help-block" ng-messages="add_user_form.confirm_password.$error" ng-if="add_user_form.confirm_password.$dirty">
          <p ng-message="required">This field is required</p>
          <p ng-message="minlength">This field is too short</p>
          <p ng-message="maxlength">This field is too long</p>
          <p ng-message="required">This field is required</p>
          <p ng-message="passwordVerify">No match!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: It was close, but it still didn't throw the mismatch error on the first keystroke. It threw the error after the field lost focus. Maybe my question wasn't clear. My fault. @developer033 you have been a great help to me for this entire project. Just like last time I eventually figured out a way to do what I wanted to do but in a very ugly and "hackish" manner.Also, i am real bad at this, I used code here from my add user form where the fields are required, in my update user form they are not required unless one of the fields is empty.

Comment: This is what I came up with...[My Solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/2QTY770qW0FtYiZ21WtP?p=preview)

Comment: @OGJoshZero, no problem man, I'm here to help others. Unfortunately, you didn't explain that you want to display the message simultaneously... by the way, you could use `$dirty` instead of `$touched` then it will keep validating while user is typing, so you don't need to do any kind of hack.. I changed my answer, check it.

Comment: Thanks bro, I accepted your answer. I'll try to figure out how to ask clearer questions in the future. I knew when I hacked that directive together that i bound everything to the view...it was ugly...lol

Comment: Where does this "user" variable come from?

Comment: @BrunoSantos the template is the same as the original post. Maybe it's a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple working solution. We can simply use `$validators` introduced in Angular 1.3.0 to achieve the same:

```js
var app = angular.module("sa", []);

app.controller("FooController", function($scope) {

});

app.directive('passwordVerify', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$validators.myPwdInvalid = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        return viewValue === scope.$eval(attrs.passwordVerify);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<form name="add_user_form" ng-app="sa" ng-controller="FooController">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
        <label>Password
            <input ng-class="{ notvalid: add_user_form.user_password.$invalid }"
                   type="password" name='user_password' placeholder="password" required
                   ng-model="user.user_password" password-verify="user.confirm_password">
        </label>

        <div class="help-block" ng-messages="add_user_form.user_password.$error"
             ng-show="add_user_form.user_password.$error.$dirty || add_user_form.user_password.$touched">
            <div ng-messages="myPwdInvalid">Password do not match</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="small-12 columns">
        <label>Confirm Password
            <input ng-class="{ notvalid: add_user_form.confirm_password.$invalid }"
                   ng-model="user.confirm_password"
                   name="confirm_password" type="password" placeholder="confirm password" required
                   password-verify="user.user_password">
        </label>

        <div class="help-block" ng-messages="add_user_form.confirm_password.$error"
             ng-show="add_user_form.confirm_password.$error.$dirty || add_user_form.confirm_password.$touched">
            <div ng-messages="myPwdInvalid">Password do not match</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me (ugly and hackish):

HTML:

```
<h1>Password Verification</h1>
<form name="pw" ng-controller="pw">
<p>
  <label for="password">New Password
    <input type="password" name="user_password" ng-model="user_password" ng-required="confirm_password && !user-password" password-verify="confirm_pasword">
    <p ng-show="pw.user_password.$error.passwordVerify">Passwords do not match</p>
    <p ng-show="pw.user_password.$error.required">This field is required</p>
  </label>
</p>
 <p>
  <label for="password">Confirm Password
    <input type="password" name="confirm_password" ng-model="confirm_password" ng-required="user_password && !confirm_password" password-verify="user_password"> 
    <p ng-show="pw.confirm_password.$error.passwordVerify">Passwords do not match</p>
    <p ng-show="pw.confirm_password.$error.required">This field is required</p>
  </label>
</p>
</form>
```

Then the script:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('pw', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.user_password = "";
    $scope.confirm_password = "";

}])
.directive('passwordVerify', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
                if (scope.confirm_password === scope.user_password) {
                    scope.pw.confirm_password.$setValidity('passwordVerify', true);
                    scope.pw.user_password.$setValidity('passwordVerify', true);
                } else if (scope.confirm_password !== scope.user_password) {
                    scope.pw.confirm_password.$setValidity('passwordVerify', false);
                    scope.pw.user_password.$setValidity('passwordVerify', false);
                }
            });
        }
     };
});
```

Comment: Since you want to validate the two inputs simultaneously, you don't need all of it. You can just change it to:`var matches = scope.confirm_password === scope.user_password;
          scope.pw.confirm_password.$setValidity('passwordVerify', matches);
          scope.pw.user_password.$setValidity('passwordVerify', matches);` and take out a lot of unnecessary code.

Comment: The bad thing in this solution is that you're now dependent of your view, if you change your form name or one of both fields, it will not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy to understand solution:

```
<input class="form-control" type="password" name="newpass"  ng-model="newpass">
<input class="form-control" type="password" name="confirmpass"  ng-model="confirmpass">
<div  ng-show="confirmpass != newpass"><hr>Password not matched</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use following.

```
<span class="error" ng-if="!register_frm.password.$invalid && !register_frm.confirm_password.$invalid && register_frm.password.$viewValue != register_frm.confirm_password.$viewValue">
Confirm Password must match with Password
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

While the above answers are correct, there is a very simple solution for this situation:

You can use a `ng-class` directive to set a class different from angularjs built-in class (`ng-invalid`) and add a simple style for it in your css. DO NOT FORGET to add `!important` to your style because angularjs overrides it ;)