# Password validation using angular

Tags: angularjs

- I want to Keep $ symbol in the password.But it is a Showing error message if the password and confirm password same also.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div ng-app="">
    <form id="registerform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate="novalidate" name="registrationForm">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : registrationForm.password.$invalid && !registrationForm.password.$pristine }">

            <input id="register-password1" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" ng-maxlength="25" ng-minlength="6" ng-required="true" onkeypress="return (event.which != 32)">

            <p ng-show="registrationForm.password.$error.required && !registrationForm.password.$pristine" class="help-block errosClass">Please enter password</p>
            <p ng-show="registrationForm.password.$dirty && registrationForm.password.$error.maxlength" class="help-block errosClass">Password cannot be more than 25 characters</p>
            <p ng-show="registrationForm.password.$dirty && registrationForm.password.$error.minlength" class="help-block errosClass">Password cannot be less than 6 characters</p>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-bottom: 10px" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : registrationForm.cpassword.$invalid && !registrationForm.cpassword.$pristine }">

            <input id="register-confirm-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" ng-model="cpassword" ng-pattern="password" required="required" onkeypress="return (event.which != 32)">

            <p ng-show="registrationForm.cpassword.$error.required && !registrationForm.cpassword.$pristine" class="help-block errosClass">Please enter confirm password</p>
            <p ng-show="registrationForm.cpassword.$error.pattern" class="help-block errosClass">Your password and confirm password not match.</p>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

[Code Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bjm9ze44/3/)

Comment: Please see the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38539417/validating-password-and-confirm-password-fields-whenever-one-or-the-other-fields?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thanks for you help

Comment: You are most welcome

Answer (score 0):

In `ng-pattern` you need to pass the regexp. Symbol `$` is the end of string in regexp.

For real validate you need to create directive like

```
export class PasswordMatchValidator {
  constructor() {
    this.require = 'ngModel';
    this.restrict = 'A';
  }

  link($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel) {
    ngModel.$validators.passwordMatch = modelValue =>
      $attrs.passwordMatch == modelValue;

    $attrs.$observe( 'passwordMatch', () => ngModel.$validate() );
  }
}
```

And use it in template like

```
<p ng-show="registrationForm.cpassword.$error.passwordMatch" class="help-block errosClass">Your password and confirm password not match.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
ng-pattern="password"
```

...is not going to be a reliable way to make sure `password` and `cpassword` are the same. Except for the case of simple alphanumeric text with no special characters, not a limitation you'd want for passwords, you can't expect a string to be self-validating with itself as a regular expression.

You need to validate by comparing `password` to `cpassword` directly.

Comment: Thanks quick response

Answer (score 0):

As was written, $ is taken as an end of the regexp.

So what helps is to escape it.

Replace `ng-pattern="password"` by `ng-pattern="password.replace('$', '\\$')"` (you escape $ by \$, double \ is to escape \ itself ;)

Comment: Thanks.What I am looking for the answer.